# Customize bean validation message

Tags: jakarta-ee, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

my question is:
Is this possible?

```
    private String a;

    @AssertTrue(message = "Value a is " + a) 
    public boolean isOk() {
       ...
    }
```

Or is there an alternative solution to get this?

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible. As a start `"Value a is " + a` won't even work on a syntactical level in Java. Strings must be constants.

Bean Validation allows to interpolate values in the messages, eg `message = "Value a is ${validatedValue}"`, but in your example it is not 'a' which gets actually validated, right?

You won't have access to other bean values or the root bean, so for now it is not possible.